# Convert nested dictionary of lists into pandas dataframe efficiently

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have a json object such that

```
{
   "hits": {
      "hits": [
         {
            "_source": {
               "TYPES": [
                  {
                     "_ID": 130,
                     "_NM": "ARB-130"
                  },
                  {
                     "_ID": 131,
                     "_NM": "ARB-131"
                  },
                  {
                     "_ID": 132,
                     "_NM": "ARB-132"
                  }
               ]
            }
         },
         {
            "_source": {
               "TYPES": [
                  {
                     "_ID": 902,
                     "_NM": "ARB-902"
                  },
                  {
                     "_ID": 903,
                     "_NM": "ARB-903"
                  },
                  {
                     "_ID": 904,
                     "_NM": "ARB-904"
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I need to unpack it into a pandas dataframe such that I get all the unique _id and _nm pairs under the _types object

```
           _ID          _NM
0          130          ARB-130
1          131          ARB-131
2          132          ARB-132
3          902          ARB-902
4          903          ARB-903
5          904          ARB-904
```

I am looking for the fastest possible solution since the number of types and number of  pairs within types can be in hundred of thousands. So my unpacking using pd.Series and using apply makes it slow and I would like to avoid it if possible. Any ideas would be appreciated. Also about exploding dictionaries or lists in a column into separate columns without using pd.Series as I encounter this use case on the regular

Comment: Can people please also provide reasons before downvoting a question willy-nilly. If there is an improvement to be made to the language then I would but I wouldn't know unless someone tells me

Comment: I upvoted your question. But there are 2 reasons I'm guessing: (1) we can't see your existing code, so can't tell if our solution(s) will be any faster than what you have now; (2) "fastest possible" is unclear - the fastest possible solution would probably involve dropping down to Cython or some other non-trivial optimization. This is why I retitled your question to "efficiently."

Comment: I cannot put the code because of company policies. I have made it clear however that I know how to arrive at the solution but need a performant solution. I am not convinced by the word efficiency here. So this was more of a general question as to what is the fastest way to convert a said dict object into pandas df (if there is one available without deep-diving into Cython)

Comment: While you can't post code, can you not provide an outline of your existing solution.. e.g. which library are you using, what function, generator or list comprehension, etc? I'm trying to *help* you improve your question so it gets more attention. Don't take it personally.

Comment: I am not being defensive. I genuinely want to make this question better in case there are others in the same boat and considering how many use-cases I have of this issue I would bet plenty of people have come across it. I did mention that I use pd.Series and apply. From what I have researched online these are slow as they iterate over each row of the dataframe. I have looked into the ast library but cannot get it to work for my purpose

Comment: Did an answer below help? Feel free to accept an answer (green tick on left), or ask for clarification.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to restructure your dictionary and flatten using `itertools.chain`.

For performance, you should benchmark with your data.

```
from itertools import chain

res = list(chain.from_iterable(i['_source']['TYPES'] for i in d['hits']['hits']))

df = pd.DataFrame(res)

print(df)

   _ID      _NM
0  130  ARB-130
1  131  ARB-131
2  132  ARB-132
3  902  ARB-902
4  903  ARB-903
5  904  ARB-904
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it this way and see if I get any benefits in performance